# How to fix "Unable to obtian configuration from 'https://localhost:5001/.wel-known/openid-configuration'"

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm setting up a new asp.net core app.
I want my app to have authentication and authorization so I'm using Identity Server 4 as another project (In the same solution).
I've been following a pluralsight guide and everything seems to work fine Until I try to authorize a token send with a http request.
Using Postman, I send a http post request to "https://localhost:5001/connect/token" and gets a token.
After getting the token, I send a GET request with Header - "Authorization : Bearer [token]" and get a 500 HTTP status code.
I've created a ".cer" file using OpenSSL.

I've searched for a solution, mainly I see solutions that are not necesserily related to my problem. The deal is, guess I'm using a pretty new version of ASP.NET CORE because the api I'm using is different.
I've tried to install the ".cer" file, didn't work.
I've read that it somehow related to two projects being the same solution, didn't find a concrete solution.
I did approve my ".cer" file using the "dotnet dev-certs https --trust" and it did approve it, but still the same.

As for code , so here's my two project's Program.cs, Startup.cs :
API Program.cs:

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseUrls("http://127.0.0.1:5000")
            .ConfigureLogging((hostingConext, logging) =>
            {
                logging.AddConfiguration(hostingConext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
                logging.AddConsole();
                logging.AddDebug();
                logging.AddEventSourceLogger();
            }).UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
    }
```

API Startup.cs:

```
    public class Startup
    {
        private IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment environment)
        {
            ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            builder.SetBasePath(environment.ContentRootPath);
            builder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
            builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(authOptions =>
            {
                authOptions.DefaultScheme = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                authOptions.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.Authority = "https://127.0.0.1:5001";
                options.ApiName = "Swap";
            });
            services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
            services.AddScoped<ITokenSetData, SqlTokensetData>();
            services.AddDbContext<DbContextTokenSet>(options =>
          options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddMvc();
        }
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseFileServer();
            app.UseMvc(ConfigureRoutes);
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        private void ConfigureRoutes(IRouteBuilder routerBuilder)
        {
            routerBuilder.MapRoute("Default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        }
    }
```

AuthServer Program.cs:

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseUrls("https://localhost:5001")
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.ClearProviders();
                logging.AddConsole();
            });

    }
```

AuthServer Startup.cs:

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services
            .AddIdentityServer()
            //.AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
            .AddSigningCredential(new X509Certificate2(@"D:\Programming Projects\Swap\swap.pfx", "password"))
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(InMemoryConfiguration.ApiResources())
            .AddInMemoryClients(InMemoryConfiguration.Clients())
            .AddTestUsers(InMemoryConfiguration.Users().ToList());    
        }
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
        }
    }
```

Here's my controller and method (if it matters):

```
    [Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller {

        [HttpGet]
        public string Hello()
        {
            return "hello";
        }
    }
```

The actual results are :
API :

```
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://127.0.0.1:5001/.well-known/openid-configuration'. ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://127.0.0.1:5001/.well-known/openid-configuration'. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ThrowIfExceptional()
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.<AuthenticateAsClientAsync>b__47_1(IAsyncResult iar)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask`1 creationTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(String address, IDocumentRetriever retriever, CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
   at IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation.IdentityServerAuthenticationHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync() in C:\local\identity\server4\AccessTokenValidation\src\IdentityServerAuthenticationHandler.cs:line 61
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 222.4963ms 500
```

AuthServer:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[20]
      Connection id "0HLMJ502OFSUM" request processing ended abnormally.
System.IO.IOException: The decryption operation failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: An unknown error occurred while processing the certificate
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslStreamInternal.ReadAsyncInternal[TReadAdapter](TReadAdapter adapter, Memory`1 buffer)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Adapter.Internal.AdaptedPipeline.ReadInputAsync(Stream stream)
   at System.IO.Pipelines.PipeCompletion.ThrowLatchedException()
   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadResult(ReadResult& result)
   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadAsyncResult()
   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.DefaultPipeReader.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
```

The expected results are "hello".
Thanks.

Comment: Try not using ips. This issue is because you are using https on local without having correct self signed certificates in place. Either try 'https://localhost:5001/.well-known/openid-configuration' or without https at all.

Comment: I'm not trying to send a GET request to 'localhost:5001/.well-known/openid-configuration', IdentityServer does it and somehow it gets blocked.

Comment: it's not identity server, its the asp.net core middleware trying to obtain your identity provider configuration. It gets blocked because you don't have proper local SSL configured.

Comment: If I understand what you mean , I need to change my code to :
options.Authority = "localhost:5001";    Unfourtunately, it doesn't work.
Do I understand correctly?

Comment: `The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.` means that your client cannot properly connect to your sts server so you need to fix that. Using http as a test like Vidmantas suggested is a good first step.

Comment: @AmitBL try `options.Authority = "http://localhost:5001";`

Answer (score 0):

Use proper launch profile where ApplicationUrl's port matches the port which is configured for JwtBearer Authority and Audience.

```
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001"; //Example
                options.Audience = "https://localhost:5001/resources"; //Example
            });
```